# Python: Extract Variables from JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing

I would like to extract a number of variables from a JSON-reponse and save it in a csv-file. 
The JSON-reponse looks as follows:

```js
{
"Response":"Success",
"Message":"Coin list succesfully returned!",
"BaseImageUrl":"https://www.cryptocompare.com",
"BaseLinkUrl":"https://www.cryptocompare.com",
"DefaultWatchlist":{
"CoinIs":"1182,7605,5038,24854,3807,3808,202330,5324,5031,178978",
"Sponsored":"1182"
},
"Data":{
"USC":{
"Id":"100954",
"Url":"/coins/usc/overview",
"ImageUrl":"/media/1383363/usc.png",
"Name":"USC",
"Symbol":"USC",
"CoinName":"Ultimate Secure Cash",
"FullName":"Ultimate Secure Cash (USC)",
"Algorithm":"SHA256",
"ProofType":"PoS",
"FullyPremined":"0",
"TotalCoinSupply":"200084200",
"PreMinedValue":"N/A",
"TotalCoinsFreeFloat":"N/A",
"SortOrder":"1233",
"Sponsored":false
```

I would like to get the following variables: *Name, Symbol, CoinName and ID*

In order to extract all the values of the JSON-response, I use the following code:

```
def getCoinList():
req = requests.get(‘https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/’).json()   
info = req[‘Data’]
coinList = pd.DataFrame(info)
coinList = coinList.transpose()
coinList.to_csv(‘coinList.csv’)
return coinList
```

However, I would like to extract only the specified variables.

```
def getCoinList():
req = requests.get(‘https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/’).json()['Data']
info = req['...'] /// How do I all four variables?
coinList = pd.DataFrame(info)
coinList = coinList.transpose()
coinList.to_csv(‘coinList.csv’)
return coinList
```

I am not sure how I can modify this code to extract only the four specified variables? Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use a dictionary

Comment: What Python version supports `‘` and `’` and doesn't need indentation? And your "JSON" isn't JSON, there are at least a few `}` missing.

Comment: what if you open your .json file like , **with open (file, 'r') as f:**... and after that you manage your dictionary getting the keys with: **yourdict.get('yourkey')** .. of course this works if you know by hand the name of the keys to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list containing several specific values in your `dict`, you need to manually create a list:

```
mylist = [req['Name'], req['Symbol'], req['CoinName'], req['ID']]
```

Or, if you want a `dict`:

```
mydict = {'Name': req['Name'], 'Symbol': req['Symbol'],
          'CoinName': req['CoinName'], 'ID': req['ID']}
```

So to write this to a csv:

```
import csv

with open('coinList.csv', 'a') as filep:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(filep)
    csvwriter.writerow([req['Name'], req['Symbol'], req['CoinName'], req['ID']])
```